# PhpUnit with jenkins. build with ant fine on terminal. but error when automate

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, phpunit

I'm following [jenkins-php.org](http://jenkins-php.org/) automation process. I'm using ant build currently. And When i run 'ant' command from terminal, all run well and BUILD SUCCESSFUL. 
But When I run it on using jenkins build, BUILD FAIL. By Console Output, the only one different is phpunit run in terminal success while jenkins build's phpunit the following error.

`phpunit:
  [phpunit] This version of PHPUnit requires PHP 5.6; using the latest version of PHP is highly recommended.
  [phpunit] Result: 1`

The rest is fine. Do You think I miss some configuration in jenkins for php ? Please let me know if u have any idea.

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with Apache Ant or Jenkins. Your version of PHP is too old for the version of PHPUnit you want to use.

Comment: Hi Mr.Bergmann, My PHP is 7.0. phpunit 5.6.1 is fine on terminal :). got error only when on jenkin.

Comment: Maybe in Jenkin' shell environment an older PHP is used? Looks like something related to your environment.

Comment: Do i need to config for php in 'Global Tool Configuration'? Where can i edit those environment? I'm new to jenkins.

Comment: Hi Mr.@Sebastian, can u please help me with that one last thing.? I appreciate it.